# Is there any way to set OobData programmatically for Bluetooth pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, pairing, out-of-band

Can the Out of Band data be set through any available interface?

The OobData class is hidden in android API but from what I understand it's still possible to perform OOB Pairing with an android device, for example using NFC SSP (secure simple pairing).
In my case I already have the oob data ( confirmation hash and random) I just can't find a way feed this data to the OS for the pairing process.
Functions like createBondOutOfBand are also hidden and have the SystemApi tag.
I cannot find any information on why they're no longer accessible, or if there is another way(interface) to perform this secure pairing process.

Any information is much appreciated.